What is the name of this simulator
I am watching some tutorials which are explaining about transistors. I find the simulator tool used in the video amazing. What is this simulator?


This circuit simulator is falstad.
And it is an online simulator that can be found here:
http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html

Actually it's called CircuitJS and the website is called Falstad, but everyone calls the simulator Falstad anyway.

Can you believe this? When I got my first job as an EE we had HSpice running on HP and SUN Microsystem workstations and I was nearly unique in my department for having an Intel 80286 CPU with an 80287 math co-processor at home to run PSpice when I wasn't at work. Home networking was limited to dial-ups running Kermit to automate FTP data transfers, which were s...l...o...w.... I hope today's generation of engineers gets the chance to look back on their careers and realize just how far the world has come. It's breathtaking. An online simulator with GUI. We'd have given our left eyes for that.

This is CircuitJS, which can be found at http://falstad.com/circuit/.

It is known familiarly as Falstad after its inventor Paul Falstad. That is not its official name though.
